# $AC^0$[subexp] vs. NC

Tags: circuit-complexity, dc.parallel-comp, circuit-depth, bounded-depth

My question is about the possibility of trading size for depth in circuits.

Under what conditions is it true (or, plausible) that $AC^0[2^{n^\delta}] \subseteq NC^i$ for some constants $\delta < 1, i>0$?

Or, is there anything known at all?

I can see that $NC^1$ circuits of depth $\epsilon\mathrm{log}(n)$ (for $\epsilon<1$) are contained in $AC^0[2^{n^\epsilon}]$. My question goes in the other direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, $\mathrm{AC}^0[2^{n^\delta}]$ is not included in NC; it is not even included in $\mathrm{SIZE}[2^{n^\epsilon}]$ for $\epsilon<\delta$. Indeed, any Boolean function on $n^\delta$ inputs, padded to input size $n$ with dummy variables, has depth-2 circuits of size $2^{n^\delta}$, but the vast majority of such functions require circuit size $\Omega(2^{n^\delta}/n^\delta)$.

By the way, the opposite inclusion can be improved: not only does $\mathrm{AC}^0[2^{n^\epsilon}]$ contain $\mathrm{NC}^1$ without the $\epsilon\log n$ depth restriction, we have, in fact,
$$\mathrm{NL/poly}\subseteq\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\mathrm{AC}^0[2^{n^\epsilon}].$$
This is a form of Nepomnjaščij’s theorem.